# When does git include the repository URL in merge commit messages?

Tags: git

it came to my attention that the merge commit messages of my team members look differently depending on who is doing the commit.

Does anyone know:
When does `git` suggest merge commit messages of the first form (i.e. stating the repo url explicitely), and when does it use the second form?

```
2017-07-05 11:34 Employee 1            M─│─┐ Merge branch 'wip-feature-1' of ssh://repo.company.com:1850/ttt/software into mainbranch
2017-07-05 10:45 Employee 2              │ │ M─┐ Merge branch 'wip-feature-2' into mainbranch
```

Thanks!

Comment: What software are you using to host your central repository at `repo.company.com`?

Comment: @Chris: The server is running GitLab.

Comment: Josh Lee's answer is correct: the default generated message depends on which commands and options you use. More interesting / compelling is the fact that these merge messages are largely useless. If you could get people to write meaningful merge messages instead, the entire question would be moot.

Comment: Yep, train your coworkers to use `pull --rebase`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think they’re using `git pull` to do their merges. I can also get this with `git merge FETCH_HEAD` after fetching (which makes sense, since `git-pull` is documented to be the same as `git merge FETCH_HEAD`).

`git merge` with any argument other than `FETCH_HEAD` (or with no argument) doesn’t produce this message, it uses ‘remote-tracking branch’ or just ‘branch’ instead.